# Bedeutung von »Saubär«

Tags: meaning, regional

Welche Bedeutung hat das Wort

> Saubär

in Deutschland?

Ich war gerade ein wenig entsetzt, als ich sah, dass die deutsche Drogeriekette DM, die auch in Österreich ein dichtes Filialnetz betreibt, dieses Wort als Markenname für Seifen und Schampons für Kinder verwendet:

[image]

Der Saubär ist in Österreich ein Synonym für einen Zuchteber, also für ein männliches Schwein, das nicht kastriert wurde, und das in der Schweinezucht eingesetzt wird. Der Daseinszweck eines Saubären ist es, Sauen zu decken. Der Saubär ist also das schweinische Gegenstück zum Zuchtbullen.

Dabei darf »schweinisch« gerne auch im übertragenen Sinn verstanden werden. »Saubär« ist nämlich auch ein Schimpfwort, vergleichbar mit »Drecksau«, das aber bevorzugt auf Männer angewendet wird, die ein versautes Verhalten zeigen (nicht nur, aber insbesondere im sexuellen Bereich).

Da wundert es mich dann doch ein wenig, dieses Wort groß auf einer Flasche Kinderschaumbad zu lesen.

Bedeutet »Saubär« in Deutschland etwas anderes als in Österreich?

Comment: "Nett" ist der "Pfirsichduft". Jemand, der das schreibt, hat noch nie in der Nähe eines Ebers gestanden...

Comment: In Österreich würde es korrekt heißen: Jemand, der das schreibt, **ist** noch nie in der Nähe eines Ebers gestanden. In österreichischem Deutsch verlangen Verben, die das Verweilen an einem Ort ausdrücken (also »stehen«, »sitzen«, »liegen«, »hängen« usw.) nicht das Hilfsverb »haben«, sondern »sein«: Ich *bin* gesessen, du *bist* gestanden, er *ist* gelegen usw.

Comment: Im "deutschen Deutsch" ist beides akzeptabel, "sein" vor allem in Süddeutschland. Ich verwende nur "haben" als Hilfsverb, wenn ich mich außerhalb meines Dialekts bewege.

Comment: Meine erster Gedanke, als ich den Titel las, war "sauber" verballhornt zu "saubär", ähnlich wie bei Werner: Hubschraubär, Bärtram, Bärbel etc. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3fMGFA_i2Q Ich bin 34, Stadtkind und habe noch nie von einem Zuchteber als "Saubär" gehört. Vielleicht wird das auch bevorzugt in Süddeutschland verwendet?

Comment: @Raketenolli Wird es. Der *Saubär* beschränkt sich  lt. Wikipedia auf den oberdeutschen Sprachraum.

Comment: @Raketenolli: Es gab tatsächlich vor einigen Jahren eine Werbekampagne mit der Verballhornung von sauber. St. Gallen benützte diesen als Werbeträger für eine Abfallentsorgungskampagne: http://www.tagblatt.ch/ostschweiz/stgallen/stadt/St-Galler-Abfallsack-wird-vierzig;art186,4284565 Der Bär ist auch das Wappentier der Stadt.

Comment: Die Bedeutung *Eber* habe ich selbst gar nicht gekannt, ich habe nur an das Schimpfwort gedacht – wobei ich es als einen besonders dreckigen *Bären* gesehen hätte *(Sau-* als Verstärkung wie bei *Sauwetter)* und nicht näher mit einem Schweinderl irgendeiner Art in Verbindung gebracht hätte.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Das Produkt wird unter diesem Namen m. W. auch in Deutschland verkauft.

Und, nein, "Saubär" bedeutet in Deutschland dasselbe wie in Österreich (Möglicherweise sind Begriffe aus der Landwirtschaft allerdings dem "modernen Menschen" heutzutage nicht mehr ganz so gegenwärtig). In meiner Mundart (Schwäbisch) wird der *Saubär* allerdings *nur* als Schimpfwort gebraucht. Man weiß zwar, dass ein Eber gemeint ist, das tatsächliche Tier heisst aber schon immer Eber, und zwar nachvollziehbar bis ins 17te Jahrhundert (Die Eberhaltung war eine wichtige Gemeindeaufgabe und wurde deswegen schon immer gut dokumentiert)

Ich habe durchaus schon gehört, dass *Saubär* als Kosename für ein Kind, das sich furchtbar schmutzig gemacht hat, verwendet wird.

Hier konnte der Werbetexter/Produktbenamser wohl der Versuchung nicht widerstehen, die *Lautähnlichkeit* zu "sauber" zu nutzen.

[Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saub%C3%A4r) bezeichnet den Begriff als "gemäßigt heftiges Schimpfwort", schwächer als "Drecksau" und "Wildsau".

Interessant ist vielleicht auch noch der *Saubär* (bei dem es sich ja nicht um einen Bären, sondern ein Schwein handelt) im Zusammenhang mit den englischen Begriff *boar* (Eber). Scheint derselbe Wortstamm zu sein.

Comment: Also hier in Berlin ist ein **Saubär** in der Tat bekannt als ein nicht reinlicher Bär, insbesondere im Gegensatz zum Waschbär. Und wird wirklich für schmutzige Kinder verwendet. Ich vermute deshalb das zugrunde legen dieser Bedeutung in Verbindung mit dem Wortspiel "sauber". Vlt. kannst du das etwas prominenter herausstellen in deiner Antwort. Ich wollte das jetzt nicht duplizieren.

Answer (score 8):

Mein Eindruck aus Südwestdeutschland ist:

- Die Bedeutung *Zuchteber* ist im Allgemeinen unbekannt. Wie [tofro auch vermutet](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/34299/5999), mag das am heute geringeren Bekanntheitsgrad landwirtschaftlicher Begriffe liegen.
- Die Verwendung als Schimpfwort ist mäßig bekannt, und zwar speziell als Schimpfwort aus Bayern. In diesem Sinn wird *Saubär* auch als sehr "harmloses Schimpfwort" verstanden (beispielsweise hatte ich einen bayrischen Lehrer, der Schüler regelmäßig mit einem Augenzwinkern "Saubär" nannte), ungefähr vergleichbar mit "Schelm"/"Schlawiner"/"Scherzkeks".
- Als Wortspiel zu diesem "harmlosen Schimpfwort" und dem Wort "sauber", sowie in Bezug auf die *wörtliche* Bedeutung des Begriffs *Saubär*, wurde wohl als humorvoller Produktname *SauBär* für ein Sauberkeits-bezogenes Produkt gewählt.

Comment: Den dritten Punkt finde ich genau passend. Ob das dann marketingmäßig gelungen ist oder nicht, ist sicher Geschmacksache. Eher nicht, meine ich.

Comment: Saubär mag zwar ein Fachbegriff sein, aber er wird auch im Sinne von *Schmutzfink* verwendet. Es ist auch (zumindest in dem mir geläufigen Sprachgebrauch) kein Schimpfwort - genauso wenig wie Schmutzfink. Ich sage zu meinen Kindern (und ich weiß durchaus aus anderen, nicht verwandten Familien, dass die das ebenso halten): Wie siehst Du denn aus, du kleiner Saubär?

Comment: @MartinPeters: Ich fand den Produktnamen eigentlich durchaus gelungen - aber das mag vollkommen darauf zurückzuführen sein, dass mir die Bedeutung als Zuchteber bis zum Lesen dieser Frage gänzlich unbekannt war, und ich die Bedeutung als "Schimpfwort" auch nur mit der harmlosen Interpretation kannte.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Ich tat mich auch schwer damit, das als "Schimpfwort" zu bezeichnen und verwende deshalb hier mehrfach Anführungszeichen. Andererseits würde ich niemanden als *Saubär* titulieren, ohne klarzumachen, dass ich es humorvoll meine - und das deutet für mich gewissermaßen darauf hin, dass es eine Art Schimpfwort (man könnte es auch "unfreundliche Bezeichnung" nennen) ist.